# What are available options for RTMP server on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, rtmp

I am trying to set up a audio chat application on heroku using open source technologies. I am ready to use either PHP, Node.js, Python or Ruby. How could I get a RTMP server running on Heroku platform. I could not find any related document on the web.

Is there any other alternatives for setting up audio chat on heroku?